# Function don't work

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I use this function :

```
function edit_post($id, $title, $content, $img) {
    global $connect;
    $id = (int)$id;
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br($content));
    $img = mysql_real_escape_string($img);
    $date_posted = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `topics` SET
                `title` = '$title',
                `content` = '$content',
                `img` = '$img' WHERE `id` = {$id}");

}
```

To make an update on database ..

and call it by this :

> edit_post($_GET['id'], $title, $content, $img);

but it not make the update i want to

Comment: Mixing `mysql and mysqli` in your code!!

Comment: one approach could be, that you write the sql into a string, echo it and see, if this is the SQL you need.

Comment: What is your database connection, mysql or mysqli? If it is mysqli you don't need the escape function if you switch to a prepared statement.

Comment: it's mysqli database connection

Answer (score 0):

Function is calling or not? Maybe you have to call this function like this:

```
$this->edit_post($_GET['id'], $title, $content, $img);
```

Comment: I add this but not work too